# Managing the z-index of sticky elements from different parents

Tags: html, css

I have run into a bit of a problem here with displaying two sticky elements that don't share a parent. I am trying to get `.the-second-sticky` (some kind of table header) to be on top of the `.dropdown-parent`'s background, which means it should have a higher z-index. At the same time, the child of `.dropdown-parent` is an expandable menu, and I would like for the menu to be over `.the-second-sticky`. But I couldn't find a way to do it, as there is no way to make a child have a higher z-index than its parent. Can anyone help me out with this?

In the snippet below, you can start scrolling to get the sticky elements to line up at the top, then click the expand button to expand the dropdown menu.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('button')
let isExpanded = false
btn.onclick = () => {
  document.querySelector('.dropdown').style.height = isExpanded ? '' : '500px'
  isExpanded = !isExpanded
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
}

.dropdown-parent {
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 50px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: red;
}

.dropdown {
  width: 500px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: green;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.the-second-sticky {
  width: 500px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 30px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

button {
  position: fixed;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class='dropdown-parent'>
  <div class='dropdown'>I should be on the very top</div>
</div>
<div class='the-second-sticky'>I should be on top of the red, but under the green when expanded</div>
<button>Toggle</button>
```

Comment: read until the end of the duplicate to see the solution using 3D tricks

Answer (score 0):

As per the placement of the elements I think with `position:sticky;` you may give `z-index: -1` to your sticky element. This will take care of not overlapping your sticky element over your dropdown. While parent of your dropdown will have `z-index : auto`.
Remember, with `position:sticky` its always better to put your element at right place inside the dom to avoid such overlapping issues.

Desired code-snippet should be as follows

```
.the-second-sticky {
  width: 500px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 30px;
  background-color: yellow;
  z-index : -1;    // <--- This should help
}
```

Comment: If I do so, the second sticky would go under the red background of the parent container.

Comment: It won't.. Check out this.  https://codepen.io/maheshkedari/pen/abWdoVL
For two items in sticky position, they will be rendered as per the sequence in the DOM and won't be overlapped.

Comment: I am not sure if that's the case, since in your snippet the second sticky goes under the red background upon scrolling.

Comment: Sticky will try to stick your element to specified top. So this overlap is taking place. If you wish to avoid it, why don't you specify different value of `top`? 
I tried with top:50px and its working. Can you check this updated codepen? https://codepen.io/maheshkedari/pen/abWdoVL

Comment: Reference: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/#sticky

Comment: Thanks for your response but that would defeat the purpose of what I am trying to achieve. I think the question this one is merged with has the right solution

Comment: No problem buddy..!! wish you luck.